# How to do a fresh install on every boot

Tags: boot, server

I want my servers to come up cleanly on each boot rather than having state which persists across boots. Short of PXE-booting, is there any way to do this? In particular, I’m curious if live-CDs do something similar (writes don’t persist—perhaps they use an in-memory filesystem)?

Comment: Be aware that *daily* liveCDs are re-built *daily* for testing purposes; ie. there is no need to perform updates as they'll get caught during the next build of the *daily* image (be it *focal* or what will become 20.04.4, *jammy* etc; also note: *daily* is a term that more accurately refers to interval in my opinion; as dailies can be built multiple times per day; or once a week depending on issues or time in the *development* cycle).   If you use a *stable* or static released daily then your boot will not have security fixes applied.

Comment: It is [LTSP](https://ltsp.org/), do not invent it by yourself.

Comment: @N0rbert LTSP seems to depend on PXE, which isn’t something I want to bite off right now (I don’t think my router supports it and I’d like to not have to learn DD-WRT at the moment).

Comment: PXE does not need special router. You setup LTSP server and PXE boot in client devices.

Comment: I need to read up more then. Everything I read suggested I at least needed to be able to twiddle DHCP settings (presumably to tell clients where to find the PXE server).

Answer (score 2):

"*I’m curious if live-CDs do something similar*"

Yes that's exactly what they do.  The live session is loaded into RAM and changes do not persist after a reboot.

You can accomplish what you are asking with a liveCD, but you can also use a USB flash drive with installation media. Just choose the "Try Ubuntu" option.

Comment: In my experience the Live ISO for Ubuntu *Server* always forces you to install the system (at least in more recent Ubuntu versions) without letting you try out the OS (like the Desktop version). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I have used in the past: The `overlayroot` package in the Ubuntu repositories.

> Description: use an overlayfs on top of a read-only root filesystem
> This package adds functionality to an initramfs built by initramfs-tools.
> When installed and configured, the initramfs will mount an overlayfs
> filesystem on top of a read-only root volume.
> .
> The changes can be written to a in-memory temporary filesystem, a
> filesystem on an existing block device, or a dmcrypt encrypted block
> device.

In other words,

- The booted **system** (/) is read-only, like a LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment. Changes can be made, but those changes are on the overlayfs, and do not persist across a reboot.
- For editable **data**, store the data on a different partition. A different partition can be mounted read/write, so those changes do persist across reboots.
- When time comes to tweak or update the system, a GRUB command will mount the system read-write. You set up your system *exactly* way you want it to boot every time, then just turn overlayroot back on and reboot.